# Difference between "new WinWindow(UITestControl.Desktop)" and "new WinWindow()"

Tags: coded-ui-tests

When initializing a `WinWindow` in CodedUI, whats the exact difference between

```
var win = new WinWindow();
```

and

```
var win = new WinWindow(UITestControl.Desktop);
```

In windows all controls' root is the Desktop, so if no parent is specified in the `WinWindow` constructor, the search of the control should start from the Desktop anyway.

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference between the results, the second constructor although makes it possible for us to specify an control as a parent of another control. It is up to us if we use the Desktop or not.